# Images aren't displaying when being sent through Amazon SES in a template created with grapesjs

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-s3, base64, grapesjs

My team and I built a web application that sends emails among other tasks. We are implementing a framework called grapesjs to build templates which are then emailed to recipients in the body of an email. The templates are being sent perfectly. They look great. EXCEPT the images are missing. In some cases, they are missing and others, the hash is present instead of the picture itself. Why aren't my images displaying? I've tested this in Gmail. When I click "show original", download it, and open it in Outlook, it displays the image(s).

See above

```
sendEmail() {
            this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
        width: '250px'
    });
    let candidateEmails = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("emailList")).value
    let subject = this.sendForm.get('subjectForm').value
    console.log(this.selectedTemplateName)
    this.templateService.getTemplate(this.selectedTemplateName).subscribe((templateData : any) => {
        console.log(templateData.Body)
        console.log(templateData.Body.data)
        let body = importTemplate(templateData.Body.data).toString();
        console.log(body)
        this.candidateService.sendEmailWithoutPositions(candidateEmails, subject, body).subscribe(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/send_email']);
        });
    })
}
```

No error messages, no image(s)

Comment: Can you share your console.log output? Where are the images coming from (I'm assuming S3)? Do you have a bucket policy attached that permits CORS and public objects?

Edit: From "When I click "show original", download it, and open it in Outlook, it displays the image(s)." this looks like a CORS problem.

Comment: Console.logs: https://imgur.com/ZqdphXl
Yes, the images are coming from an S3 bucket. Checking on policies now.

Comment: Have you configured anything to support public read on the objects in that S3 bucket? Objects in S3 are denied public access by default. Edit: I can't really tell from the code where the images are supposted to be (only 4 logs in this snippit but more in image). Can you clarify? Are you sure that tbe Base64 encoded string can be decoded into the image? Maybe there's an encode issue?

Comment: It is also possible that the images are just being blocked by the email provider you are using, and require you to manually permit the rendering of those images when you view the email.

Comment: So I checked the permissions and under Permissions and the Bucket Policy is empty, but the CORS Configuration has this in it: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:4200</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>

I didn't set the bucket up. I'll check for public read

Comment: This CORS rule says only requests from the server running at origin localhost:4200 have permission to make POST, PUT, DELETE, and GET requests. You can access the objects directly, but if a different origin makes the request (between you and the object), then it will be blocked. This different origin can be the server running email software (Gmail, outlook, hotmail, yahoo, etc.). Here's a doc: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/

Comment: There should just be a little jenkins image in between text that says top text on top and bottom text on bottom. I'm not positive about the base64. I know that there is a base64 encoder/decoder online I found through Google and when I put the hash into it, it spat out the image.

Comment: Ah, yeah, if the image has already been accessed and encoded, then it may just be the email client blocking it. Is there a way to add the email address sending those emails to a trusted list within your email account's preferences, of some sort?

Comment: I noticed that. So far, I've been testing it on localhost 3000 so that may be the issue. Does it make sense for the text part to go through without the image?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense. There would be nothing to encode. Im guessing the Array(25225)[...] are the pixel values of the image that's being encoded, so the image should be read correctly.

Comment: Yea, apparently either this template making framework, grapesjs, or AWS S3 automatically encode images with base64 so no way around it that I've found.

Comment: That's my conclusion as well about the array

Comment: Is there away to view the raw html of the email? I believe there's a button in the options menu (3 vertical dots?) in Gmail.

Comment: Yes, there is. It's a bit long to add here. Something I should look for?

Comment: Can you render it? Does it show the image?

Comment: If i copy the hash directly following "base64," and pasted it into this site: https://www.base64decode.net/base64-image-decoder
and yes, the image of the jenkins logo is decoded.
EDIT: I've done some more googling and it looks like Gmail and many other email providers don't support base64 encoded images any more. I'm not positive if it's the grapesjs we are using to create templates that is encoding the image or if it's S3.

Comment: In this case, can you try embedding the S3 image then? (src="https://....") Would also help to add alt text since you can't really test what email services have images off by default.

Comment: So I got it to work. All of the images I was pulling straight from google, I would inspect and they would all say base64. So I decided to try getting to the source of an image. When I did that, it led me to images whose source was now https://......jpg. So once I got the source, instead of downloading the image and adding it to a template, I dragged and dropped and that allowed the image to keep it's https heading instead of being hashed into the base64. Doing this allows the images to be sent through the service we built. Thank you for your help.